# java RAM problems

Tags: java, android

I've a problem with my android. First I wrote an application in C language (for PC), which used lot of RAM - about 500 MB for tables. Then I tried to rewrite the same code for Android in Java (Eclipse)... and the problems started.

It has taking a lot of time to create (on htc desire hd) static tables (the same size = 500MB) - first I think that is working but...then somebody told me that single aplication on Android can only use 24 MB RAM. it is true? How can I make this size bigger? How can I solve this restriction?

Comment: There's no way you can use 500MB of memory as some of the most expensive mobiles have 512MB in total for the OS. Why can't you have those tables on "disk" and access them when you need them?

Comment: Your phone is not a PC.  Use your ram sensibly and you'll be ok.  Perhaps your tables contain a lot of data which can be removed (ie symmetrical reflections.  Or perhaps you have to solve it another way.

Answer (score 5):

Most phones don't even have 500+MB of RAM, and even if they did, Java structures take up far more space than C structures (object overheads). What are you trying to achieve? You can't solve the restriction. Instead, use a more efficient data structure.

Comment: I arleady use htc desire HD which has 768MB RAM. i will soon receive from htc new phone with 1GB RAM.
thats tables for solving rubics cubes.

Comment: Solving rubicks cubes? There's apps on Android which work on the device itself and solve Rubicks cubes. See http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-solve-rubiks-cube-with-any-android-device/. Certainly doesn't need a huge amount of memory to run.

Answer (score 3):

You clearly need to design your Android client in a way that can consume services. Your phone is not supposed to be used as a service provider (database server).

I would recommend you do all your database work on the server side and simply query and present the data on your Android (client). The least amount of processing you do on your phone the better, since these are presentation devices (battery constrains, limited amount of memory and processing power, etc.) not data/number crunching devices.

You can raise the limit to 48Mb in certain devices (tablets) by using a configuration option witch i do not remember but is in the documentation, but is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's true. You have to optimize your code (use flash memory to store some data) or just use external server for running your algorithms.

Comment: @pitrpo, @Adam -> thanks, thats good tips, I will lern/search about that.